# Can not call Extension Method in c#

Tags: c#, .net

I have following class;

```
public static class statiClass
{
    public static DataTable ToPivotTable<T, TColumn, TRow, TData>(
 this IEnumerable<T> source,
 Func<T, TColumn> columnSelector,
 Expression<Func<T, TRow>> rowSelector,
 Func<IEnumerable<T>, TData> dataSelector)
    {
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    var rowName = ((MemberExpression)rowSelector.Body).Member.Name;
    table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(rowName));
    var columns = source.Select(columnSelector).Distinct();

    foreach (var column in columns)
        table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(column.ToString()));

    var rows = source.GroupBy(rowSelector.Compile())
                     .Select(rowGroup => new
                     {
                         Key = rowGroup.Key,
                         Values = columns.GroupJoin(
                             rowGroup,
                             c => c,
                             r => columnSelector(r),
                             (c, columnGroup) => dataSelector(columnGroup))
                     });

    foreach (var row in rows)
    {
        var dataRow = table.NewRow();
        var items = row.Values.Cast<object>().ToList();
        items.Insert(0, row.Key);
        dataRow.ItemArray = items.ToArray();
        table.Rows.Add(dataRow);
    }

    return table;
}
```

And I can not call him from another class like below;

```
dtTA.ToPivotTable(
                item => item.Year,
               item => item.Product,
               items => items.Any() ? items.Sum(x => x.Sales) : 0);
```

It throws an error like ;

```
DataTable' does not contain a definition for 'ToPivotTable' and no accessible extension method 'ToPivotTable'
```

I searched a lot and didn't find any solution interestingly.

How can i solve this ?

Comment: do you have a) a refernce if that class is in another project b) a using <namespace>

Comment: yes, they are in the same namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first convert dtTA to IEnumerable source
then , you can call ToPivotTable by source
like following(holp this helpful) :

```
//first convert dtTA to IEnumerable source
        var source = dtTA
            .Select()
            .Select(x => new 
            {
                Year = (string)x["Year"],
                Product = (string)x["Product"],
                Sales = (int)x["Sales"]
            }).ToList();
        //then , you can call ToPivotTable by source
        source.ToPivotTable(
            item => item.Year,
           item => item.Product,
           items => items.Any() ? items.Sum(x => x.Sales) : 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

You register your extension method in `IEnumerable` interface (indicated by the following argument in the method definition: `this IEnumerable<T> source`), while (judging by the error message) trying to call it from a `DataTable` instance. The error is appearing simply because `DataTable` does not implement `IEnumerable` ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable?view=netframework-4.7.2)). Simply replace `IEnumerable` with `DataTable` or other interface which is implemented by the `DataTable` class, adapt your method to these changes and the method should work just fine.

Comment: what should i have change?

Comment: write an extension for the class you want to extend. IE change the `this` clause

Comment: The type of the first argument in your `ToPivotTable` method - it indicates a class or an interface which should be extended with your method. Currently you extend `IEnumerable`, which is not implemented by the `DataTable` class which you are trying to invoke your method from. Have a look at that link: https://csharp.net-tutorials.com/csharp-3.0/extension-methods/

Comment: Thank you gor helps but i am not advanced on coding. Could you please rewrite on this answer?

Comment: That would require me to probably rewrite the whole method - that's not my role here. Sorry!

Comment: What i didn't understand is, this class used by 100s of developers and i am not sure , if they used this way.

Comment: They probably used that method and invoked it on a collection (like a List or an Array, anything that extends IEnumerable), which is fine and probably that's the purpose of this method - to convert a collection into DataTable. What you are trying to do, is to invoke that method on an existing DataTable - which is not allowed.

Comment: Write another extension method that extends DataTable. In that method, build an `IEnumerable<TheDataTableRowType>`, (possibly using `yield` but I suspect there's a `Rows` property, that you can play cast games with), and then call back into your existing method (which I haven't really looked at).

Answer (score 0):

Would it not be the case that you transform the DataTable into an IEnumerable via the `AsEnumerable` method?

Am I missing something?

```
dtTA.AsEnumerable().ToPivotTable(
           item => item.Year,
           item => item.Product,
           items => items.Any() ? items.Sum(x => x.Sales) : 0);
```